# Copying joomla site to new server but maintaining the new servers admin password

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I ftped all the files to the new server (except configuration.php this remained the same so it didn't need updating), I then exported the database without the table _user, and imported it into the new servers database.

I thought because I did this I would be able to log in with the username and password I created when I installed joomla on the new server however I'm getting this error message when I try to log in to the backend 'Failed to authenticate'.

Any Idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Did you look for other posts with similar problems and learn from their solutions? Did you try anything to fix the problem? We cannot possibly answer your question in its current form (except by guessing) because it does not contain enough information.

Comment: Did all of those things.. think I would bother coming here without trying myself what other information do you need I gave exactly what I did and the result I am getting by doing so

Answer (score 0):

Not migrating the users table is most likely the reason why you can't log in.  If you are looking for an easy way to migrate a Joomla installation between servers look into the Akeeba Back Up extension.

You can't really pick and choose which tables to migrate as Joomla core relies on all of them.